# Packing a callback function into a templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make a callback function structure that I can put a generic function and all the arguments it will receive so that at any time during execution I can call it.

To me, it would look something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename... targs>
class CallbackFunction {
private:
    targs... args;
    std::function<T(targs...)> fun;

public:
    CallbackFunction(std::function<T(targs...)> fun, targs... args) : fun(fun), args(args) {}

    T call () {
        return this->fun(this->args);
    }
};
```

So that I can do something like this:

```
CallbackFunction cb = CallbackFunction(printf, "Hello World!\n");

cb.call();
```

There are 2 problems to doing this that I know of:

1- You can't store targs... args. Compiler says `data member type contains unexpanded parameter pack 'targs'`

2- You can't send args  to the function as-is. You need to unpack it somehow. Compiler says `expression contains unexpanded parameter pack 'args'`

What is the correct way to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class T>
using CallbackFunction=std::function<T()>;

CallbackFunction<void> cb = []{printf("Hello World!\n");};

cb();
```

The type `T` must be part of the type, so barring C++17 you must list at least it.

`targs...` is only an internal detail.  `std::function` does type erasure on the signature and can handle storing any set of `targs...` or other state.

An object that can be called, and returns `T`, and stores some state, is a `std::function<T()>`.  The rest is dross.

If you really must

```
template <typename T>
class CallbackFunction {
  std::function<T()> fun;

public:
  template<class...targs>
  CallbackFunction(std::function<T(targs...)> fun, targs... args) : fun([=]{ return fun(args...); }){}
  T call() const {
    return fun();
  }
};
```

optimizing this with move semantics is a bit more work.  Find an implementation of `std::apply`:

```
  template<class...targs>
  CallbackFunction(std::function<T(targs...)> fun, targs... args) : fun(
    [fun=std::move(fun), args=std::make_tuple(std::move(args)...)]()->decltype(auto){
      return std::apply(fun,args);
    }
  ){}
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I was restricted to C++14. But A+ for completeness.

Comment: I just finished testing the first solution. I wanted it to be more hidden that that, but it seems impossible to do that, as the implementation of templates is not as smart as it would seem in C++14. I just really wanted it to work like it does in python where you can just do `def call(fun, *args): fun(*args)`

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho C++ has compile-time type checks.  This means you have to prove that data is of the right type at compile time.  Python only has run-time type checks.  Which means it has to store almost everything as a tagged union (or variant) over the restricted set of python primitive types and do runtime type checking and throw or convert whenever things don't line up.  The advantage is that type-correct code avoids entire categories of hard to test for run time errors.

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho At the same time, this is C++, and in C++ you *can* implement runtime type checking in a way similar to python.  The language doesn't help you that much, and your code base ends up being foreign and only marginally compatible with other C++ code.  You are usually better off writing python, then using python-C or python-C++ bindings, or some other scipring language, if you want scripting-like type looseness.  And that isn't that good either.  Really, just learn to write type-correct code.